# WebSphere Application Server Error

Tags: ibm-was

Am new to this domain and trying to install websphere version 8.5.0 in my server.. Service has been successfully installed and I started the service also... when am trying for deployment am unable to in browser.... This displaying the error as follows

**Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /**

Please anyone help me to get out from this one.... Thanks in advance..... Am waiting.......

**Detailed Error:**

Error Page Exception
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:

```
Error Message: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
com.ibm.isclite.common.Messages, key en_US
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: /logon.jsp
Error Stack:
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.isclite.common.Messages, key en_US
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:172)
 at com.ibm.isclite.common.util.TitleUtil.getBundle(TitleUtil.java:80)
 at _ibmjsp._logon._jspService(_logon.java:274)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
 at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:965)
 at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
 at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
```

Error Page Exception:

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet
[_ibmjsp._error]: Could not find required class - class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _ibmjsp._error
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet:
Error Stack:
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [_ibmjsp._error]: Could not find required class - class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _ibmjsp._error
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1490)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1469)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:619)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3263)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:3791)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:89)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
```

Comment: Did you resolve this by any chance? I am having the same problem :(